# Angular intellisense is not working in the typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

My application (Angular11) is well. but today when I open my application, I found this error as a pop-up window in my vs code window right side down corner:-`The TypeScript language service died 5 times right after it got started.The service will not be resterted`

So for that, I try to solve this problem by watching this video:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBhXW5PMLjs  (1 minute). because it's the same error as me.but it's failed to resolve my issue Also i found a new issue.

My issue is something like that now:-

[image]

**Please look at the above picture.** Here I am trying to import `memberService` file,so here expectation is when I hit the `tab` button, should import the member service file. automatically.

but when I hit the `tab`. failed to import this file automatically.

[image]

For that found error.I don't know and did not understand how I resolve this issue.I am absolute beginner in Angular.please help.

Comment: Does it work when you import the MemberService manually?

Comment: Try with 'ctrl' + 'space' , or 'ctrl' + '.'

Comment: @Tino when i manually import error is gone.but i want naturally work automaticlly

Comment: @JuanBerzosaTejero please read my post carefully.